# Let $n$ be a positive integer. Determine the number of solutions to $x_1 + \cdots + x_k \leq n$ with nonnegative integer solutions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, multisets

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Determine the number of solutions to $x_1 + \cdots + x_k \leq n$ with nonnegative integer solutions. Determine the number of solutions with positive integer solutions.

I understand why every positive solution of $x_1 + · · · + x_k = m$ corresponds to an ordered partition of $m$. However, I do not understand why the number of positive solutions of $x_1 + \cdots + x_k \leq n$ is

$$\sum_{m=k}^{n}\binom{m-1}{k-1}.$$

Similarly, I do not understand how using multisets we obtain $\binom{n+k}{k}$ for the nonnegative integer solutions. Can someone explain this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics). Just add another non-negative variable to make it into an equality.

Comment: Do you understand why the number of positive solutions to $x_1 + \cdots + x_k = m$  is $$\binom{m-1}{k-1}?$$

Comment: @user Yes, the number of ordered $k$-partitions of $n$ equals $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider some positive solution of the inequality $$x_1+\cdots+x_k\le n\tag1.$$ It is necessarily a solution of an equation $$x_1+\cdots+x_k=m\tag2$$ for some $m:\ k\le m\le n$. Therefore the number of solutions of the inequality (1) is the sum of the numbers of solutions of the equations (2) for all $m:\ k\le m\le n$:
$$\sum_{m=k}^n\binom{m-1}{k-1}=\binom{n}k.
$$
The last expression can be obtained also in a direct though somewhat tricky way.

The same formula work for the number of non-negative solutions as well. Just replace $n(m)$ with $n(m)+k$.

Comment: Your last (unnumbered) equation is called the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: Hello @user , sorry but I don't understan very well the non-negative part. Can you explain that? I try to use multisets but I am not getting it.

Comment: @AlexisSandoval The number of the compositions of a number $n $ into $k $ non-negative parts is equal to the number of the compositions of a number $n+k$ into $k $ positive parts. Think about subtracting 1 from the every part of the latter.